# Sprout SEO Plugin - Title Tags Not Appearing Correctly

Tags: plugin-sproutseo, seo

I have chosen to append all title tags with the site name on my site (see screenshot). However, none of my title tags are being updated when I click update. All title tags are appended with "- Site Name" and have appeared that way prior to adding the Sprout Plugin. I've tried changing the character, but nothing is updating the title tags.

Is there somewhere else in Craft that allows for management of title tags that I'm missing? Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: You're in the right place. Can you share how you are outputting your metadata in your templates?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Ben! I've included an example from our source code. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. I'm not a developer, but an SEO strategist. Let me know if this isn't what you meant, really appreciate your help!

Comment: This is how meta data is appearing in the source code: 
{% if entry is defined and entry.seoDescription|length %}<meta name="description" content="{{ entry.seoDescription }}" />

<title>{% if entry is defined and entry.seoTitle|length %}{{ entry.seoTitle }}{% elseif entry is defined and entry.title|length %}{{ entry.title }}{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %} - {{ siteName }}</title>

Comment: It looks like the issue may be that you have a custom implementation of Sprout SEO and are not using the Sprout SEO variables in your source code. Sprout SEO can only manage some of the settings in the control panel if the right tags were used during implementation. The code at the end of your example is a hard coded dash and siteName value (`- {{ siteName }}`) that Sprout SEO has no control over.

Comment: Sprout SEO can usually be implemented in a way where everything is manageable in the control panel. As a first step, I'd recommend reaching out to your developer and asking why they chose a custom implementation over the standard implementation. If you still find yourself stuck, we'll need to get a better understanding of your whole set up. Feel free to reach out to sprout@barrelstrengthdesign.com and we're happy to try to better diagnose what options you have to get the control you need.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick responses! I'll reach out to our development team and have them take a look.